# React Uncaught TypeError: myarray.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I keep getting this error - Uncaught TypeError: itemList.map is not a function
I was under the impression itemList was just supposed to be an array? There is an array being returned in console log for itemList.

The following code is just a popup modal that pulls in data from a users shopping cart.

```
function Example(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState('');
  const url = wordpressurl + "checkout/";

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getItems() {
      const value = await localforage.getItem('cart_key');
      await CoCart.get("cart?cart_key=" + value).then((response) => {
        setItemList(response.data.items);
      })
    }
    console.info(itemList);
    if (!itemList) {
      getItems();
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={handleShow} className='cartlable'>Cart</div><div id="cartcount"><div className="cartcount">0</div></div>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton className="me-2">
          <Modal.Title>Your Cart</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body id="cartlist">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-8 text-start"><h5>ITEM</h5></div>
              <div className="col-1 text-center"><h5>QTY</h5></div>
              <div className="col-2 text-end"><h5>SUBTOTAL</h5></div>
              <div className="col-1 text-end pe-2"></div>
            </div>

            {itemList.map((cartitem) =>
              <div className="row align-middle cartitemrows">
                <div className="col-1 text-start"><img src={cartitem.featured_image} className="cartimage" alt="" />{cartitem}</div>
              </div>
            )}

            <div className="row pt-3"><div className="col-11 text-end"><h5>TOTAL : <span id="carttotal"></span></h5></div></div>
            <form id="form-id" action={url} method="get" encType="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="cocart-load-cart" />
              <button id="your-id">Checkout</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Btw this is what shows up in console if I declare the useState as a string instead of an array like so `const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);` -

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {item_key: '698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668', id: 111, name: 'Cuff Beanie', title: 'Cuff Beanie', price: '3000', …}
1: {item_key: '7ce9004ae3ad190443d43d7f81241060', id: 107, name: 'Womans T-shirt - MED Womens', title: 'Womans T-shirt', price: '6000', …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the default state of your list to an empty string.

Use

```
 const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
```

to set the state to an empty array.

String objects do not have a map function.

Array objects(even empty ones) do have the map function

Also make sure that your response from the server is an array

Comment: I did actually try that but it gives me an empty array now using `const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);`. When I have it set to a string I at least get an array back in console. I understand what you are saying but I get nothing returned in console and nothing showing in the cart list at all with that edit. There's something else up

Comment: This shows up in console when i use a string instead of array to declare the useState - `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {item_key: '698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668', id: 111, name: 'Cuff Beanie', title: 'Cuff Beanie', price: '3000', …}
1: {item_key: '7ce9004ae3ad190443d43d7f81241060', id: 107, name: 'Womans T-shirt - MED Womens', title: 'Womans T-shirt', price: '6000', …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

Comment: You are calling a promise on an await async function, check what the return value is rather than the promise. I.e. ```const results = await CoCart.get("cart?cart_key=" + value);console.log(results);``` You will still need to set the useState as [] for the first render

Comment: Thankyou for the replies mate. I realised I was going about populating what was in the shopping cart completely the wrong way. I ended up restructuring it completely.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are defining the value of `const [itemList, setItemList] = useState('');` as an empty string and map is an array method so insted of an empty string you can use an empty array.

```js
const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
```

Comment: Ok but when I have it set to a string I get an array back in console. I get what you are saying though and I changed the declaration to be an array as you suggested, but now I get nothing returned in console, nothing showing in the cart list at all. If I set it as a string I get the array in console

Comment: This shows up in console when i use a string instead of array to declare the useState - `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {item_key: '698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668', id: 111, name: 'Cuff Beanie', title: 'Cuff Beanie', price: '3000', …}
1: {item_key: '7ce9004ae3ad190443d43d7f81241060', id: 107, name: 'Womans T-shirt - MED Womens', title: 'Womans T-shirt', price: '6000', …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I was going about trying to populate the contents of a users shopping cart the wrong way, for example I didn't even need useEffect. So I restructured it completely and ended up with this -

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import CoCartAPI from "@cocart/cocart-rest-api";
import localforage from "localforage";
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';

const wordpressurl = "http://localhost/wordpress/";
const CoCart = new CoCartAPI({
  url: wordpressurl,
});

function Example(props) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  const [cartKey, setCartKey] = useState('');
  const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = useState('');
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  const url = wordpressurl + "checkout/";

  async function getItems() {
    setShow(true);
    const value = await localforage.getItem('cart_key');
    setCartKey(value);
    await CoCart.get("cart?cart_key=" + value).then((response) => {
      var carttotal = response.data.totals.subtotal / 100;
      const result = response.data.items;
      setItemList(result);
      setCartTotal(carttotal);
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => getItems()} className='cartlable'>Cart</div><div id="cartcount"><div className="cartcount">0</div></div>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton className="me-2">
          <Modal.Title>Your Cart</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body id="cartlist">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-8 text-start"><h5>ITEM</h5></div>
              <div className="col-1 text-center"><h5>QTY</h5></div>
              <div className="col-2 text-end"><h5>SUBTOTAL</h5></div>
              <div className="col-1 text-end pe-2"></div>
            </div>
            {itemList.map(({ id, featured_image, name, value, quantity, totals, item_key }) => (
              <div key={id} className="row align-middle cartitemrows">
                <div className="col-1 text-start"><img src={featured_image} className="cartimage" alt="" /></div>
                <div className="col-7 text-start">{name}</div>
                <div className="col-1 text-center">{quantity.value}</div>
                <div className="col-2 text-end">{totals.total}</div>
                <div className="col-1 text-end pe-2"><i className="bi bi-trash" onClick={() => removeProduct(item_key, value)}></i></div>
              </div>
            ))}
            <div className="row pt-3"><div className="col-11 text-end"><h5>TOTAL : <span id="carttotal">{cartTotal}</span></h5></div></div>
            <form id="form-id" action={url} method="get" encType="multipart/form-data">
              <input type="hidden" name="cocart-load-cart" value={cartKey} />
              <button id="your-id">Checkout</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

async function removeProduct(productkey) {
  await CoCart.delete('cart/item/<' + productkey + '>')
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Response Status:", response.status);
      console.log("Response Headers:", response.headers);
      console.log("Response Data:", response.data);
    });
}
export default Example
```

No doubt there could be a few improvements that could be made but as is it works perfectly